# Jquery image slider auto play

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an autoplay from my slider jquery section. What can i do this ?

I have a next & a prev button but I want to add an auto-play and also when mouse hover over image that slide automatically stopped.

Anyone can help me here ?

This is my **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/CAfzi)** page from codepen

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

Comment: What kind of slider do you want? Keep Moving slider or slide one by one image? Check [this](http://slideshow.hohli.com/docs/demo06.html) out

Comment: @HendryTanaka I want Auto play only moveLeft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your script like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
  function do_slide(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      moveLeft();
    }, 1000);
  }
  do_slide();


     $('ul li').hover(function(){
       clearInterval(interval);
     });
      $('ul li').mouseleave(function(){
       do_slide();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the end of your javascript code before the final "}); "

```
      var myparam1 = true;

      (function(){
       if (myparam1){
        moveLeft();};
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
      })();

      $( "#slider" )
        .mouseenter(function(){myparam1 = false;})
        .mouseleave(function(){myparam1 = true;});
```