# I want to add auto slide to this script can any one help me out?

Tags: jquery, slide

Hi Friends I have a image slider on my site

slides images by click on preview and next button.

My question is: is it possible to add auto start instead of onclik ?

Here is my codes:
I want to add auto slide to this script can any one help me out??   doesn't have the auto play option. It just slides on mouse click event.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var showCaseItems = $('.show-case-item').hide();

        var splashes = $('.splash').hide();
        //get each image for each slide and set it as a background of the slide
        //            splashes.each(function () {
        //                var img = $(this).find('img');
        //                var imgSrc = img.attr('src');
        //                img.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        //                $(this).css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + imgSrc + ')', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat' });
        //            });

        splashes.eq(0).show();
        showCaseItems.eq(0).show();

        var prevIndex = -1;
        var nextIndex = 0;
        var currentIndex = 0;

        $('#banner-pagination li a').click(function () {



            nextIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));

            if (nextIndex != currentIndex) {
                $('#banner-pagination li a').html('<img src="assets/img/slidedot.png" alt="slide"/>');
                $(this).html('<img src="assets/img/slidedot-active.png" alt="slide"/>');
                currentIndex = nextIndex;
                if (prevIndex < 0) prevIndex = 0;

                splashes.eq(prevIndex).css({ opacity: 1 }).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
                splashes.eq(nextIndex).show().css({ opacity: 0 }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500, function () { });

                showCaseItems.eq(prevIndex).css({ opacity: 1 }).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                    showCaseItems.eq(nextIndex).show().css({ opacity: 0 }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200, function () { });
                });

                prevIndex = nextIndex;
            }

            return false;
        });


    });
```

Comment: why dont use already existant sliders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i presume your have a ul inside your div called banner-pagination. hard without seeing your html. If you don't you should have. a ul should always surround lis

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var slideCount = $('#banner-pagination ul li a').length;
var slideWidth = $('#banner-pagination ul li a').width();
var slideHeight = $('#banner-pagination ul li a').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#banner-pagination').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#banner-pagination ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#banner-pagination ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#banner-pagination ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('#banner-pagination ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#banner-pagination ul').css('left', '');
    });
};


function do_slide(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      moveLeft();
    }, 1000);
  }
  do_slide();


 $('ul li').hover(function(){
   clearInterval(interval);
 });
  $('ul li').mouseleave(function(){
   do_slide();
 });
 });
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155717/jquery-image-slider-auto-play)