# Use JQuery to auto slide between images - with my html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code:

```
<div class="slider" id="mySlider" >
  <div class="slide-group">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/image2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/image3.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After every div with class slide there's the img as you can see above.

Using jquery, how can I get it to auto slide between images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery image slider auto play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155717/jquery-image-slider-auto-play)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to cycle through the slides.

Set it so after x time move to the next slide

The snippet below isn't functioning completely properly, but it gives you a general idea

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.setInterval(nextSlide, 1000);
});

function nextSlide() {
  var $cur = $('.slide.active');
  var $next = $cur.next();
  if(!$next) $next = $('.slide-group').children()[0];
  console.log($next);
  $cur.removeClass('active');
  $next.addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.slide {
  display: none;  
}

.slide.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider" id="mySlider" >
  <div class="slide-group">
    <div class="slide active">
      SLIDE 1
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      SLIDE 2
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      SLIDE 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jon Raasch's simple jquery slideshow is the absolute classic, in my opinion. I've seen it used on many sites.

http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

His example uses a fade, but you can change it to a slide or even Ken Burns it easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-jquery-image-scroller/

is just one example of tutorials for image scrollers using jquery.

Just google "jquery image scroller" then if you have further issues come back and see us :)