# Making a jQuery carousel automatically slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've created my image slider and it is set to slide when one of the buttons is clicked. But now I'm struggling to make the slide automatically and stop when the mouse hovers over the sider. Could you show me or at least tell me how to do this? Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slide_count = $(".carousel li").length;
  var slide_width = $(".carousel li").width();
  var slide_height = $(".carousel li").height();
  var cont_width = slide_width * slide_count;
  
  $(".cont").css({ height: slide_height, width: slide_width});
  $(".carousel").css({ width: cont_width, marginLeft: - slide_width });
  $(".carousel li:last-child").prependTo(".carousel");
  
  function next_slide(){
    $(".carousel").animate({
      left: + slide_width
    }, 400, function(){
      $(".carousel li:last-child").prependTo(".carousel");
      $('.carousel').css('left', 0);
    }
    );
  }
  
  function prev_slide(){
    $(".carousel").animate({
      left: - slide_width
    }, 400, function(){
      $(".carousel li:first-child").appendTo(".carousel");
      $(".carousel").css("left", 0);
    }
    );
  }
  
  $("#next").click(function(){
    next_slide();
  });
  $("#prev").click(function(){
    prev_slide();
  });
  
});
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;/*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.carousel li{
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 350px;
}

.carousel li img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#next{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id="next">
  </div> 
  <div id="prev">
  </div> 
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-3.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a `setInterval()` where you call your slider function every `x` seconds, and put a flag on it to not run if the mouse is over it.

Something like

```
var SECONDS_INTERVAL = 1000; // 1s
var mouseHoverFlag = false;

setInterval(function() {
    if (!mouseHoverFlag) {
        next_slide();
    }
}, SECONDS_INTERVAL);
```

And change that `mouseHoverFlag` to `true` whenever the user has the mouse over the div that contains it.

```
$('.carousel').hover(function() {
    mouseHoverFlag = true;
}, function () {
    mouseHoverFlag = false;
});
```

You could use `setTimeout` and kill it every time that the mouse gets in but I think that's too heavy, performance wise.

Comment: Why would anyone downgrade the answer when it perfectly fits?

Comment: Thanks that works exactly how I wanted it to. Just one question though about the hover function for .carousel. I've never seen a two functions put together like that. Am I right in assuming that while you hover it is true and when you stop hovering it exits the function but first activating the second function setting it to false?

Comment: Right. So check the API doc for it on jQuery and you'll see that `.hover()` takes *two* functions. One triggers when mouse is going `in`, and the second when it's going `out`. So we set the flag to `true` when the mouse goes in (first function running), and to `false` when mouse is out (second function runs)

Comment: And why do you use the var SECONDS_INTERVAL = 1000; when you could just simply put the amount of seconds you want in the setInterval function? like }, 1000);

Comment: @Reece only because of good coding practices. It's a constant, and I like to declare this kind of stuff. It's really a preference thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my edited version. We have to use setInterval function for automatic slide. Next we add hover event listener to carousel. If we are hovering, our variable preventSlide will change to true and if we stop hovering, variable will be changed back to false, which means auto slide.

```js
var preventSlide = false;
$(".carousel").hover(function() {
        preventSlide = true;
}, function() {
    preventSlide = false;
});

setInterval(function () {
    if (!preventSlide)
        next_slide();
}, 3500);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slide_count = $(".carousel li").length;
  var slide_width = $(".carousel li").width();
  var slide_height = $(".carousel li").height();
  var cont_width = slide_width * slide_count;
  
  $(".cont").css({ height: slide_height, width: slide_width});
  $(".carousel").css({ width: cont_width, marginLeft: - slide_width });
  $(".carousel li:last-child").prependTo(".carousel");
  
  function next_slide(){
    $(".carousel").animate({
      left: + slide_width
    }, 400, function(){
      $(".carousel li:last-child").prependTo(".carousel");
      $('.carousel').css('left', 0);
    }
    );
  }
  
  function prev_slide(){
    $(".carousel").animate({
      left: - slide_width
    }, 400, function(){
      $(".carousel li:first-child").appendTo(".carousel");
      $(".carousel").css("left", 0);
    }
    );
  }

  var preventSlide = false;
  $(".carousel").hover(function() {
        preventSlide = true;
  }, function() {
        preventSlide = false;
  });

  setInterval(function () {
if (!preventSlide)
      next_slide();
  }, 3500);

  /*$("#next").click(function(){
    next_slide();
  });
  $("#prev").click(function(){
    prev_slide();
  });*/
  
});
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;/*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.carousel li{
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 350px;
}

.carousel li img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#next{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id="next">
  </div> 
  <div id="prev">
  </div> 
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-3.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @Bernhard explanation was added.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a setInterval and clearInterval for automatic slide. Also it is good to calculate which slide you are in at the current animation. Briefly,

```js
var timer;
var rotator = function(){
    nextSlide();
};
timer = setInterval(rotator, 5000); // your desired timer
$('.carousel').hover(function(){ clearInterval(timer), function(){ timer = setInterval(rotator, 5000); });
```

you can optimize the code far better, but the basic solution is like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });
```

[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155717/jquery-image-slider-auto-play)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time interval as an option in the carousel. You can also set the pause option on hover.

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: 500, pause: "hover"});
```